# Tikz: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tikz-pgf

After reading many related questions here about "Missing number, treated as zero", I still do not understand why the following example results in such an error message:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}



\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\clip(2.5,-1.5) rectangle (6,2);
\draw(4+{sin(0)}, {cos(0)}) circle(4pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `4+{sin(0)}` to `{4+sin(0)}`. The mathematics routines only apply to stuff inside curly brackets.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but the rationale is wrong: try, for example, `\draw (4+0,0) circle (4pt);`: math expressions work fine without curly braces. The curly braces are required around the entire expression _if and only if_ it contains parentheses.

Comment: @PaulGessler That condition is a suffucient one. Not necessary ;)